# How to interpret coefficients in polynomial regression?

Tags: statistics, polynomials, regression, quadratics

I am working on my thesis (study) about poverty incidence rate and its socio-economic factors using second-order polynomial regression without interaction. The final model in my study is

PovertyIncidenceRate = 43.027 + .989(InflationRate) + .069(UnemploymentRate) - .442(CohortSurvivalRateinSecondarySchools) - .0000009(Population) - 0.035(InflationRate^2) + .138(UnemploymentRate^2) - .019(CohortSurvivalRateinSecondarySchools^2) - 0.0000000000001(Population^2)

How would i interpret these parameter estimates/coefficients (specifically the quadratic ones)? Please help me. Thank you and God bless you! :)

Comment: Do you have the standard deviation for each of the regressed parameters ?

Comment: I afraid i do not have. Can you help me in interpreting the quadratic coefficients, tho?

Comment: They just mean that the model is not linear with repect to some variables and that a quadratic polynomial better reproduce the data. Try to think in only one dimension.